# C# XML list<int>

Tags: c#, xml, list, class

I have a user input screen where user enters the Name and number associated. The output xml expected is

```
<Names>
    <Name>XYX</Name>
    <Asso>
        <Num>1</Num>
        <Num>1</Num>
        <Num>1</Num>
        <Num>1</Num>
        <Num>1</Num>
        <Num>1</Num>
        <Num>1</Num>
        <Num>1</Num>
        <Num>1</Num>
    </Asso>
</Names>
```

As there are many `<Name>` tag. I created a class to store the values like

```
public class Name{public string Name;public list<int> Num;}
```

while declaring say, `Name[] instance = new Name[10];`, for the 11 instance of the class.
I set the values of the instance[0], instance[1] with the Num values as well as the Name.

whereas when i try to print out the XML, while using the

`foreach (Name allintance in instance)` for writing the XML file. I am having the Name values properly, but the Num values are not written(its only empty tags).

Kindly let me know whats the issue.. also let me know where is there a better approach.

@Added Info
Class File

```
    public class Name    {
    public Name()
    {
        Num = new List<int>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> Num { get; set; }
}
```

and the code for assigning values is

```
                        instance[0] = new Name();
                    instance[0].Name = textbox_Name.Text.ToString();
                    instance[0].Num = NumList;
```

I have defined the NumList as `List<int>` and added the int values i got from the form.

And to write out the XML file

I Use XMlWriter and Append each Name and also the associated Num values as in above mentioned tags. My problem is going by this approach, i am able to get the Name entries in the XML tags. But Num tag results in empty tags.

Comment: what's your problem? It's unclear.

Comment: though you are not saying how you are getting XML, I am presuming that you are using xml serialization.

Comment: I am not using serialization.. Just XMLwriter and trying to dumping out the values from the class instance..

Comment: Side note: `new Name[10]` makes an array of *ten* names (accessible via indexes 0..9), not 11.

Comment: Show us your code to write to `Num` and to write it file.

Comment: @svick - Do let me know if you still need any info..i have added more info to the question..

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you posted. Are you sure `NumList` contains the numbers? If yes, then the problem is most likely in the code to write XML, could you post that?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Name
{
    public Name()
    {
        Num=new List<int>();
    }

    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name{get;set;}

    [XmlArray("Num")]
    public List<int> Num{get;set;}
}
```

to generate xml:

```
private void GetXML(Name n)
{
    var xmlsr=new XmlSerialize(typeof(Name));
    var ms=new MemoryStream();
    var tr = new XmlTextWriter(ms,Encoding.Unicode);
    xmlsr.Serialize(tr,n);
    var sb=new StringBuilder(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());//xml for object n
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately i wanted something like this.. The User Enters the "Name" in the textbox and fields to enter appropriate Num entries for the each Name. The Num entries are also filled in textboxes. Now the rule is, There can be as many entries as "Name", but the total Num entries (adding up Num entries for each "Name") should be 64. Because of this, i need to validate all the Name entries before generating the XML tags.